# Python sqlite insertion disappears?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am using Flask and sqlite3 in my Python script. I have the code below that is inserting a name in the database and writes it out correctly:

```
def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv


@app.route('/addReceiverHandler', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def addReceiverHandler():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        query_db("INSERT INTO receivers(name) VALUES(?)", [title])

        for receiver in query_db('select * from receivers'):
            print receiver[1], 'has the id', receiver[0]

        return 'ok'
```

The id col is auto incrementing and the right value is assingned when I do an insertion. However, when I run this script a second time, with some other name, it's like the first insertion never existed and the new value has the same id as the first one had. I have inserted some rows directly from the sqlite3 terminal interface and they are always printed. What is wrong? It feels like the inserted value from my script is only temporary stored in some way.

Comment: Are you running `commit`?

Comment: nope. I am following this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/sqlite3/ and I did not see any commit statement in the part that I read. How should I use that?

Comment: I think there is no commit in the example because they only doing selects. You may read the sqlite documentation before using it http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html

Comment: See the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).